# await keyword doesn't wait in dart

Tags: dart

I'm using await keyword to wait for a method to complete and return something and then use switch statements to execute block of code based on the method returned value, but it doesn't await for it's value and when i try to print the value the output is null!

here is the code:

```
 PhoneNumVerification status = await accountRecoveryAdmin.verifyUserPhoneNumber(phoneNum);
 print(status); // prints null because it didn't wait for the method to complete
 switch (status) {
 // some code
 }
```

and here is the method:

```
enum PhoneNumVerification {
     failed,
     verified,
     wrongInput,
     smsVerificationNeeded
}

Future<PhoneNumVerification> verifyUserPhoneNumber(String phoneNum) async {
if (phoneNum.isEmpty ||
    !phoneNum.startsWith('01') ||
    phoneNum.length != 11) {
  return PhoneNumVerification.wrongInput;
}
try {
  await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: '+2$phoneNum',
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
    verificationCompleted: (_) {
      return PhoneNumVerification.verified;
    },
    verificationFailed: (exception) {
      print(exception.message);
      return PhoneNumVerification.failed;
    },
    codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      return PhoneNumVerification.smsVerificationNeeded;
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null,
  );
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return PhoneNumVerification.failed;
}
}
```

Comment: It did wait.  The problem is that `verifyUserPhoneNumber` doesn't return a value on its success path.

Comment: but it does return PhoneNumVerification.verified!

Comment: `verifyUserPhoneNumber`'s `try` block returns nothing.  It passes *callbacks* that have return values, but those return values are never returned to `verifyUserPhoneNumber`'s caller.

Comment: how do i correct that then?

Comment: can you please provide an answer with the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await accountRecoveryAdmin.verifyUserPhoneNumber(...)` does wait.  The problem is that `accountRecoveryAdmin.verifyUserPhoneNumber()` didn't return a value.  If you run `dartanalyzer` on your code, it should report that not all paths through `verifyUserPhoneNumber` return a value.

Here's a simplified version of your code to make the problem more obvious:

```dart
Future<PhoneNumVerification> verifyUserPhoneNumber(String phoneNum) async {
  // ...

  try {
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      // ...
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return PhoneNumVerification.failed;
  }
}
```

You can see the `try` block does not return a value.  It passed callbacks that have `return` statements, but that just specifies what those callbacks return; they are not what `verifyUserPhoneNumber` returns.

One way to fix it would be to make those callbacks set a variable in `verifyUserPhoneNumber`'s scope, and later return that:

```dart
Future<PhoneNumVerification> verifyUserPhoneNumber(String phoneNum) async {
  // ...

  try {
    PhoneNumVerification result;
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      // ...
      verificationCompleted: (_) {
        result = PhoneNumVerification.verified;
      },
      verificationFailed: (exception) {
        // ...
        result = PhoneNumVerification.failed;
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
        // ...
        result = PhoneNumVerification.smsVerificationNeeded;
      },
      // ...
    );

    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return PhoneNumVerification.failed;
  }
}
```

### Edit:

It's not clear to me what the `Future` returned by [`FirebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html) represents.  It could just signify that the request was sent, not that the verification completed.  If you want your function wait for verification to complete, you could do:

```dart
Future<PhoneNumVerification> verifyUserPhoneNumber(String phoneNum) async {
  // ...

  try {
    final verificationComplete = Completer<PhoneNumVerification>();
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      // ...
      verificationCompleted: (_) {
        verificationComplete.complete(PhoneNumVerification.verified);
      },
      verificationFailed: (exception) {
        // ...
        verificationComplete(PhoneNumVerification.failed);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
        // ...
        verificationComplete(PhoneNumVerification.smsVerificationNeeded);
      },
      // ...
    );

    return await verificationComplete.future;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return PhoneNumVerification.failed;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please verify that one of the callbacks that you passed to `_auth.verifyPhoneNumber` is actually invoked before `_auth.verifyPhoneNumber` completes.  You also might want to initialize `result` to some new `unknown` value to make it clearer whether any of the callbacks are being invoked or not.

Comment: i tested that now and the result was that it printed unknown first and then printed "code sent" (i mean 'code sent' callback was executed after verify function got completed!) do you know why is this happening ?!

Comment: The bug then lies in `_auth.verifyPhoneNumber`, which apparently completes its returned `Future` before invoking one of its callbacks.